# Wordpress - Loading JS files after footer

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Thanks for reading,

How would I load my JS files after the footer instead of being in the header

example:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Changed to

```
</footer>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</htmL>
```

I've tried

```
    wp_register_script( 'cycle', 'http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js', '', '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cycle' );
    wp_register_script( 'site', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/site.js', '', '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'site' );
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're looking to load it in the footer instead of the header?

Comment: Just to save load speed it just these 2 scripts in particular they should be loaded from the footer there is no reason to load it from the header

Comment: I'ts just my custom js and a image slide show script

Comment: you can use async and/or defer attribs on the script tags to get the same effect

Comment: @jezuitazus It looks like you're already using the `$in_footer` parameter correctly, those scripts *should* already be appearing in the footer instead of header. Do any scripts that are loaded in the header have either of those as a dependency?

Comment: @mtinsley The only dependancy is Jquery but the method I tried above does not seem to move them to the footer at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter dictates where to enqueue the script, in footer (true) or in header (false - default):

```
<?php wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

You have to **hook** the scripts righteously (please follow the inline comments):

To hook to the front-end:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'function_name' );
```

To hook to the admin panel:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'function_name' );
```

Here's how you should proceed:

```
<?php
function themeslug_load_scripts() {
    //registering the scripts, the last parameter will dictate where they should enqueue
    //and you are saying: yes, in_footer
    wp_register_script( 'cycle', 'http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js', array(), '', true);
    wp_register_script( 'site', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/site.js', array('jquery'), '', true); //we are setting a dependency - yes depend on jQuery - means load jQuery first

    //actually rendering the scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cycle' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'site' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_load_scripts' );
```

or you can simply try:

```
<?php
function themeslug_load_scripts() {
    //actually rendering the scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'cycle', 'http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js', array(), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'site', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/site.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_load_scripts' );
```

And, clear your browser cache when working with JavaScripts. Load the page and see page source. It'll do the *thing* for you. :)

#### Reference:

- [`wp_register_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)
- [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to add js to a page or post, may I suggest a simple and free plugin? it is called   [CTJ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/css-javascript-toolbox/). you put code blocks in it and add to header or footer as you like.